# Configuring InMemory Derby DB

Tags: derby, in-memory-database

We are currently making a research on using Apache Derby as an in memory database provider in one of our applications. 
We start derby with the Glassfish asadmin

```
asadmin start-database --jvmoptions="-Xms256m -XMX57344m"
```

(Yes so much memory...)

Currently we are looking into optimization tips found in the Derby guide, like:

> You can change the default database page size with the 
>   derby.storage.pageSize property, described in the "Derby properties"
>   section of the Java DB Reference Manual. For example:
>   derby.storage.pageSize=8192

But with the asadmin started DB and the in memory connection, I cannot seem to find how to do this configuration.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that controlling the Derby page size will have almost no benefit for the in-memory database configuration. Controlling the page size offers benefits for the I/O subsystem that writes pages to persistent storage, but when you use the in-memory database configuration you aren't writing any database pages to persistent storage, hence the page size is very unlikely to matter.

Comment: That was just a sample, we are currently looking for how to configure that damn Derby.

Comment: Welcome to Derby! Here's some material to get you started: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/devguide/cdevsetprop34818.html

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that, but I don't understand, where should be my derby.properties, where should I put it.
As again: I am not using an "installed" version of Derby, just the one, that can be started with glassfish asadmin tool.

Comment: There is no such thing as an installed version of Derby, as Derby is designed to be an embedded DB. Every running copy of Derby has a "home" directory, though. Try searching your hard disk for 'derby.log' (it will probably be somewhere under your glassfish folder.

Comment: So does that mean I have to create the derby.properties file in the same directory, where I can find the derby.log?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know a lot about glassfish, only about Derby itself, and Derby can be configured in MANY ways. I take it you searched your hard disk and didn't find derby.log anywhere? The location of derby.properties depends on the notion of the Derby "system home": https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/devguide/cdevdvlp27610.html#cdevdvlp27610